# Help with typo errors on these math codes

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, math-operators, mathjax

So I have come across some math expressions that I really need to read through. However, for some reason these codes shows on some part of the document in the browser and I have no idea what these are and I am hoping if someone could translate into some image or whatever these things are. Thank you so much!!

```
a.
$$\frac{D}Dt} \thbf{S} = \frac{\partial \mathbf{S}}{\partial }+\mathbf{v} \cdot \nabia \mathbf{S}$$

b.
5\mathbf{v} 

c.
$$ fracDDt mathbS - fracpartial mathbf Spartial t + mathty cdot nabla mathbfS $$ fracDDt mathbfS $$

d.
$$ fracDDt mathbfS - fracpartial mathbfSpartial mathfy cdot nabla mathbfS $$ fracDDt mathbfS $$

e.
Smathbfvs 

f. 
$$ \frac{D}Dt} \thbf{S} = \frac{\partial \mathbf{S}}{\partial }+\mathbf{v} \cdot \nabia \mathbf{S} $$

g. 
5\mathbf{v}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: mathjax is mostly off topic here (it is javascript) but see https://mathjax.org, their site has a "getting started" link where you can paste in examples and see results. Your first has some typos, it should be `$$\frac{D}{Dt} \mathbf{S} = \frac{\partial \mathbf{S}}{\partial }+\mathbf{v} \cdot \nabla \mathbf{S}$$` see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgQxk.png)

Comment: Please choose a meaningful title for your question. At c-e there are many missing backslashes.

Answer (score 3):

errors such as nabia for nabla make it look like this has been mangled by an optical character recognition system?

Without any context, it is hard to guess what the original expressions were but this may get you started. It runs without error in latex (and the expressions would also work on a mathjax-enabled web site)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

a.
\[
\frac{D}{Dt} \mathbf{S} =
 \frac{\partial \mathbf{S}}{\partial t}+\mathbf{v} \cdot \nabla \mathbf{S}
\]

b.
\[
\mathbf{v} 
\]

c.
\[
\frac{D}{Dt} \mathbf{S} - \frac{\partial\mathbf{S}}{\partial t}
    + \mathbf{y} \cdot \nabla \mathbf{S}
\]
\[
\frac{D}{Dt}\mathbf{S}
\]

d.
\[
\frac{D}{Dt} \mathbf{S} - \frac{\partial \mathbf{S}}{\partial t}
   \mathbf{y}\cdot \nabla \mathbf{S}
\]
\[
\frac{D}{Dt} \mathbf{S}
\]

e.
\[
\mathbf{v}s 
\]

f. 
\[
\frac{D}{Dt} \mathbf{S} = 
   \frac{\partial \mathbf{S}}{\partial t}+\mathbf{v} \cdot \nabla \mathbf{S}
\]

g. 
\[\mathbf{v}\]

\end{document}
```